# Ruby naming convention / double underscore / useful stuff

Tags: ruby, methods, naming-conventions

I know there is `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, and `__send__`.

From the `Delegator` class there are `__getobj__` and `__setobj__`.

**Is there any other useful "strange" double underscore goodness present in the Ruby standard library?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a complete list for Ruby 2.1:

- [`__callee__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__callee__) (Kernel)
- [`__dir__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__) (Kernel)
- [`__method__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__) (Kernel)
- [`__id__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-__id__) (BasicObject)
- [`__send__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-__send__) (BasicObject)
- [`__ENCODING__`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/defs/keywords#L11) (keyword)
- [`__LINE__`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/defs/keywords#L12) (keyword)
- [`__FILE__`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/defs/keywords#L13) (keyword)

From [delegate](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/index.html):

- `__getobj__` (Delegator)
- `__setobj__` (Delegator)
- `__getobj__` (SimpleDelegator)
- `__setobj__` (SimpleDelegator)

From [drb](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/drb/rdoc/index.html):

- `__drbref`
- `__drburi`

From [irb](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/index.html):

- `__evaluate__`
- `__exit__`

From [tk](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/tk/rdoc/index.html):

- All the methods start with a double underscore

Answer (score 0):

There's also the encoding keyword: [`__ENCODING__`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/defs/keywords#L13):

```
puts __ENCODING__ # => UTF-8
```